# Vertical spacing of \underset and other tweaks

Tags: spacing

please consider following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand{\uunderline}[1]{\underline{\underline{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\[  
    s=\left(
    a_1,
    \underset{\big\uparrow}{a_2},
    a_3,
    \uunderline{a_4},
    a_5,
    a_6
    \underset{\underset{\big{a_0}}{\big\uparrow}}{,}
    a_7,
    d^{\left(k\right)},
    a_8,
    a_9
    \right)
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

1. As you see the `\underset` produces ugly spacing around the comma. Is it possbile to prevent that so the commas and thier spacings are all the same?
2. Is it possible to let the left/right-parenthesis not to consider the `\underset`'s / `\uparrow`'s?
3. With my Miktex distribution pdflatex throws a error: `Missing delimiter (. inserted). ...set{\underset{\big{a_0}}{\big\uparrow}}{,}`. I guess thats related to the `\big` but if leave it out the `a_0` gets too small (desired is the same size as the other `a_i`'s). How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `stackengine` package has an explicit definition`\useanchorwidth` which, if set `T`rue), ignores the width of the stacked material and takes only the width of the "anchor" material.  Of course you have to use the `stackengine` syntax.

Optional arguments are available to change the gap of the underset, as demonstrated in the case of the `a_0` term.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\def\useanchorwidth{T}
\stackMath
\newcommand{\uunderline}[1]{\underline{\underline{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\[
    s=\bigl(
    a_1,
    \stackunder{a_2}{\scriptstyle\big\uparrow},
    a_3,
    \uunderline{a_4},
    a_5,
    a_6
    \stackunder[8pt]{,{}}{\stackunder{\scriptstyle\big\uparrow}{a_0}}
    a_7,
    d^{\left(k\right)},
    a_8,
    a_9
    \bigr)
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: there's an awfully large gap above the second arrow.

Comment: @barbarabeeton It was done purely for demonstration purposes, as explained in the last line of the text before the MWE.

Answer (score 2):

this approach requires `mathtools` rather than `amsmath`.

the two `\underset` elements can be ignored by using `\smash`; note that this
eliminated depth will have to be compensated for later if something is to
print below this equation.  since the height of either smashed element
is not greater than that of the unsmashed elements, no compensation is
needed.

the `a_0` below the second arrow can be restored to normal size
by setting it in an `\mbox`, which doesn't scale, and its width can be
ignored by setting all that within `\mathclap`.

since the arrow is also wider than the comma, that also needs to be enclosed
in the `\mathclap`, but that leaves the width of that element a bit narrow,
so the comma looks too tight.  therefore, the class of that entire element
is reset to `\mathpunct` to restore the proper comma behavior.

finally, the `\mbox`ed `a_0` is closer to the arrow than it would be if
left unboxed, so a `\mathstrut` is inserted to restore the height.

a bit complicated, but it gives good practice at segmenting math structures
and putting them back together with the proper spacing.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand{\uunderline}[1]{\underline{\underline{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\[  
    s=\left(
    a_1,
   \smash{\underset{\big\uparrow}{a_2}},
    a_3,
    \uunderline{a_4},
    a_5,
    a_6
    \mathpunct{
     \smash{\underset{\mathclap{\underset{\mbox{$a_0\mathstrut$}}{\big\uparrow}}}{,}}}
    a_7,
    d^{\left(k\right)},
    a_8,
    a_9
    \right)
    \vphantom{\underset{\mathclap{\underset{\mbox{$a_0\mathstrut$}}{\big\uparrow}}}{,}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

**edit:**

Prompted by a comment, a `\vphantom` has been added so that text following
the display will be spaced properly.  (Again, not tested.)

Comment: You sure about the vertical spacing of what follows?

Comment: @egreg -- you mean the space between the arrow and the `a^0` or the likelihood that the `\smash` will leave the expression with no depth greater than the parens and double underline?  (i didn't test that, so didn't want to swear to it.)

Comment: I meant: try with some text after the equation. There will be overlap, because of `\smash`.

Comment: @egreg -- i did mention that, in the second paragraph (but weaseled because i didn't actually test it).  of course, if i'd been smart enough to use `\big` rather than `\left`, etc., that wouldn't have been a concern, and i could have forgotten about the `\smash`.

Comment: you should always complement your smashs with vphantoms.

Comment: @peter -- Done.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just don't use `\left` and `\right`, whilst fixing the underset in a different way.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand{\uunderline}[1]{\underline{\underline{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\[
    s=\bigl(
    a_1,
    \underset{\big\uparrow}{a_2},
    a_3,
    \uunderline{a_4},
    a_5,
    a_6
    \mathpunct{\underset{\underset{\makebox[0pt]{$a_0$}}{\makebox[0pt]{$\big\uparrow$}}}{,}}
    a_7,
    d^{\left(k\right)},
    a_8,
    a_9
    \bigr)
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

More human input:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand{\uunderline}[1]{\underline{\underline{#1}}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\zerounderset}[3][\mathord]{%
  #1{\vtop{
    \let\\\cr
    \baselineskip\z@skip\lineskip.25ex
    \ialign{\hidewidth$##$\hidewidth\crcr
      \omit$#3$\cr
      #2\crcr
    }%
  }}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[  
    s=\bigl(
    a_1,
    \zerounderset{\big\uparrow}{a_2},
    a_3,
    \uunderline{a_4},
    a_5,
    a_6
    \zerounderset[\mathpunct]{\big\uparrow\\a_0}{,}
    a_7,
    d^{\left(k\right)},
    a_8,
    a_9
    \bigr)
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Three suggestions and a comment:

- Load the `ulem` package and use its `\uuline` macro instead of defining a macro called `\uunderline`.
- Use the `\substack` and `\mathclap` macros to place the arrow and `a_0` terms below the comma. If desired, use a `\mathpunct` directive to assure the normal spacing around the comma in question.
- Don't autosize the parentheses; instead, use `\bigl(` and `\bigr)`.
- Incidentally, the `ngerman` package is deprecated; load babel with the option `ngerman` instead.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}  % <- new 

\begin{document}
\[  
    s=\bigl(
    a_1,
    \underset{\big\uparrow}{a_2},
    a_3,
    \uuline{a_4},
    a_5,
    a_6
    \mathpunct{\underset{\mathclap{\substack{\big\uparrow \\ \textstyle a_0}}}{,}}
    a_7,
    d^{(k)},
    a_8,
    a_9
    \bigr)
\]
\end{document}
```